# MVC Ajax action completes if i break at first line then stop debugging

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, debugging, asp.net-mvc-controller

I'm using MVC4 and VS2012.

In my client code I have a jquery post that calls a controller action that performs a database update and returns a json result.

Everything works fine. However, if I put a breakpoint on the first line of my action method the program execution pauses there as expected. If I now click stop the program terminates as expected. However my database updates??? Using Fiddler I can see that the action is completing and a result is coming back from my action.

I am not double submitting the action or anything like that.

Is this the default behaviour. Is there a setting that terminates ajax request on stopping debug?

Regards

Phillip